# When I use axios in a loop, the param was wrong

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a problem when I use the axios in a loop.
I gave different params to send request
But get the same response

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const _ = require('lodash');
const querystring = require('querystring');

//This part is about the request address and params
const url = "https://api-wanbaolou.xoyo.com/api/buyer/goods/list";
let param_default = {
    game: "jx3",                        //don't need change
    "sort[single_count_price]": 1,      //don't need change
    size: 500,                          //10    don't need change
    page: 1,                            //2     don't need change
    //zone_id: "z01",                     //z01   i need use the array(blow) item to instead of
    //server_id: "gate0115"               //gate0115  i need use the array(blow) item to instead of
};
const server_map = [
    {zone_id:'z01',server_id:'gate0115'},
    {zone_id:'z01',server_id:'gate0101'},
    {zone_id:'z05',server_id:'gate0519'},
    {zone_id:'z05',server_id:'gate0514'},
    {zone_id:'z05',server_id:'gate0502'},
    {zone_id:'z08',server_id:'gate0807'},
    {zone_id:'z21',server_id:'gate2106'},
    {zone_id:'z24',server_id:'gate2402'},
]

//then I use a loop to send request
 _.each(server_map,function (server,i){
 
  //I need change different param for every request
  let param = _.merge(param_default,server)
  
  //use axios
  axios.get(url,{
    params : param,
    paramsSerializer: function (param) {
        return querystring.stringify(param)
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    //I get the wrong data.
    //All the data is the last one's 
  })
 
 })
```

So.why?
I think in this loop.
the param is different.
so the response should be correct.
But I get all the same data as the last param.
Can u help me?
Thanks a lot !! *^_^*